# Mi host virtual me redirige al dashboard de xampp en Linux

Tags: linux, xampp, virtualhost

Tenía un virtual Host en Xampp en Linux y me funcionaba a la perfección. Resulta que de un día para otro ha dejado de funcionar correctamente pues cuando intento acceder a el este me redirige al dashboard de Xampp

Lo primero que hice fue dirigirme a la carpeta /etc

> 127.0.0.1      projectlaravel.test

Luego me dirijo a la ruta /opt/lampp/etc/extra y dentro del archivo httpd-vhost.conf tengo la siguiente configuración

```
<VirtualHost projectlaravel.test:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/projectlaravel/public"
    ServerName projectlaravel.test
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/projectlaravel/public">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
    <\Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

He visto otra preguntas similares con respuestas pero he intentado y sin resultados. Agradecería la ayuda